# How to Trim the SOAP response generated by IWS during RPGLE service program call

Tags: web-services, soap, ibm-midrange, rpgle

How to handle large complex response data structures, for Service Programs exposed as webservices with [IBM Integrated Web Services for IBM i (IWS)](http://www.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/iws/)?

**Detailed Description of the Issue:**

I have an exposed a procedure like GetRiskItemList() with a response data structure like "RiskItemListResponse" (*See Definition Below*).

The average usage of the nested array "HomeContentsList" is 10 elements, thus during normal operation 190 elements are unused. Thus significant bloat is generated into the SOAP XML result.

My requirements is to cater for up to 200 items.

For simple arrays IWS allows a variable to be designated as the COUNTER for the number or elements actually used. Which IWS uses to generate XML tags for those number of elements.

**Request**

Do you know of a way to "Trim" the XML, to excluded the unused elements of the nested array?

*RPGLE Code Extract:*

```
 d GetRiskItemList...
 d                 pr
 d i_request                           likeds(RiskItemListRequest) const
 d o_response                          likeds(RiskItemListResponse)

 ?*--------------------------------------------------
 ?* Web Service Response Data Structure
 ?*--------------------------------------------------
 d RiskItemListResponse...
 d                 ds                  qualified template
 d BuildContentsList...
 d                                     likeds(BuildingContentsEntity)
 d                                     dim(200) 
 d BuildingList...
 d                                     likeds(BuildingEntity)
 d                                     dim(10) 
 d RiskHeading...
 d                               50a
 d BenefitsHeading...
 d                               50a
```

Comment: You could use BIF `%ALLOC` or the C API for `malloc()` to allocate only as much memory as you need - you'd have to make some changes to your code and the complexity would go up. The vast majority of RPG programmers I've met are NOT familiar with pointers and such. Unless I had an overwhelming reason to solve the problem that way I would just stick with what you're doing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM added "Detect Length Fields" option.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/library/i-integrated-web-services-server/